# Is it possible that code of method from a referenced dll gets inlined in my own code?

Tags: c#, .net, inlining

A while ago I've read something about 'inlining'. The .Net compiler will inject code (inline) from small methods to make execution quicker.

Is it possible that code of method from a referenced dll gets inlined in my own code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, at JITting time.

Not at compile time.

Which means that your assembly will only contain the code you wrote it with, but when it is JITted into native machine code at runtime, the JIT compiler might inline small methods from other assemblies into your own code.

Comment: This is correct since inlining never occurs during compilation, only jitting.

Comment: And in the situation of ngen.exe compilation that Jonathan Allen talks about in his answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If you don't pre-compile the assembly using ngen.exe then the JIT compiler can inline across assemblies automatically.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? I'm not familiar with the ngen.exe.

Comment: C# is compiled to IL code. The JIT or Just-in-time compiler turns it into machine code when it gets run on the user's computer. Sometimes you want to turn it into machine code earlier. To do this you use the program call ngen or "native image generator".

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, No.

But if the Lib of the DLL is available (DLL stands for Dynamically Linked Library, something we can not link statically) it might happen.

Auto inlining as an step of optimization, is only performed on small functions or functions used very rarely, But always on libs.

To conclude, A static link library (*.lib in Windows or *.a in Unix) could be copied into your program but a dynamic link library (*.dll in Windows or *.so in UNIX) couldn't.

In case of .NET or similar frameworks, the story is a little different.

Comment: The question is tagged "c#" and ".net" so I think it's safe to assume Kees *is* asking about .NET.

Comment: Yep... it's about .Net dll's. Nevertheless the observation, albeit off topic, is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

its generally very possible.
but you cant decide yourself, its the compiler which decides:

check that:  http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/08/c-inline-methods-and-optimization/

Comment: The given link talks about classes within one binary, not about classes from referenced DLL's right?

Comment: this is right, but especially cause its the JIT-compiler who does it, it should for my understanding happen identically